# vmlinuz.efi : not found error

Tags: 13.04, virtualbox

I am using ubuntu-builder_2.4.1-gb3-1_all.deb Version 2.4.1 Debian package (Gambas 3) in my host machine which runs Ubuntu 13.04. I am using the same version 64-bit iso to customize it using the ubuntu-builder.gambas. Everything works fine, and I created the iso file. But when I run it in qemu or virtualbox, it shows a popup message box saying `/casper/vmlinuz.efi: file not found`. The screenshot shown below is from VirtualBox:

[image]

In the casper directory of the iso made by the builder there is no file named vmlinuz.efi

Comment: In that folder you don't have `vmlinuz.efi`, but there is some file named `vmlinuz` only?

Comment: no, there is no file which has name starting with vmlinuz.

Comment: And in 13.04 iso (sorry I don't have any copy to check)? Probably is something related to [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/wubi/+bug/1134770) (depending on the version you can have vmlinuz(.efi))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found out a way to rectify this problem. All you have to do is to remove the installed kernel in  the iso file, and install a new one.

1) Remove initrd.img and vmlinuz

```
rm initrd.img vmlinuz
```

2) Remove the kernel files

```
apt-get purge linux-image-*
```

3) Install kernel generic version

```
apt-get install linux-image-generic
```

This one solves my problem.